# Replace all NA values for variable with one row equal to 0

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Slightly difficult to phrase, as far as I saw none of the similar questions answered my problem.

I have a data.frame such as:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4),
                  val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))

df1

   id val
1   a  NA
2   a  NA
3   a  NA
4   a  NA
5   b   1
6   b   2
7   b   2
8   b   3
9   c  NA
10  c   2
11  c  NA
12  c   3
```

and I want to get rid of all the NA values (easy enough using e.g. filter() ) but make sure that if this removes all of one id value (in this case it removes every instance of "a") that one extra row is inserted of (e.g.) a = 0

so that:

```
  id val
1  a   0
2  b   1
3  b   2
4  b   2
5  b   3
6  c   2
7  c   3
```

obviously easy enough to do this in a roundabout way but I was wondering if there's a tidy/elegant way to do this. I thought tidyr::complete() might help but not entirely sure how to apply it to a case like this

I don't care about the order of the rows

Cheers!

edit: updated with clearer desired output. might make desired answers submitted before that a bit less clear

Comment: So you want to add rows with 0 only if all the values for particular `id` is 0?

Comment: only if they're all NA for a particular id

Comment: @RobertHickman There seems to be some confusion about your desired output. Could you update your question with the expected  output based on this `df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4), val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))` ? Thanks to @VivekKalyanarangan for the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(val = ifelse(row_number() == 1 & all(is.na(val)), 0, val)) %>% 
 na.omit()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
> # Groups:   id [2]
>   id      val
>   <fct> <dbl>
> 1 a         0
> 2 b         1
> 3 b         2
> 4 b         2
> 5 b         3
> ```

Comment: (+1) Seems like the most robust answer here. Would be marginally more concise using `replace(val, all(is.na(val)) * 1, 0)` instead of the `ifelse(...)`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Good suggestion. I usually try and avoid `ifelse` in general

Answer (score 3):

We may do

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% do(if(all(is.na(.$val))) replace(.[1, ], 2, 0) else na.omit(.))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
#   id      val
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 a         0
# 2 b         1
# 3 b         2
# 4 b         2
# 5 b         3
```

After grouping by `id`, if everything in `val` is `NA`, then we leave only the first row with the second element replaced by 0, otherwise the same data is returned after applying `na.omit`.

In a more readable format that would be

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  do(if(all(is.na(.$val))) data.frame(id = .$id[1], val = 0) else na.omit(.))
```

(Here I presume that you indeed want to get rid of all `NA` values; otherwise there is no need for `na.omit`.)

Comment: @markus, right, I had assumed that that's the goal. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like op wants to retain the first row and replace the `val` column of that row with `0` where *all* `val` is `NA` for a group. Check my ans pls. Agree with @markus, it does seem tricky

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, that's what I initially thought, but "*and I want to get rid of all the NA values*" suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
df1[!(duplicated(df1$id) & df1$val == 0), ]

  id val
1  a   0
5  b   1
6  b   2
7  b   2
8  b   3
```

Comment: Would this work for `id`s that contain `NA`s and non-`NA`s? Try with `df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2), val = c(NA, 1, 2, 3))`

Comment: I think this is the best so far (I'll leave it open for another hour or so to see)

would maybe change to 
    df %>%
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
    .[!(duplicated(.$id) & .$val == 0), ]

Answer (score 1):

Base R option is to find groups with all `NA`s and `transform` them by changing their `val` to 0 and select only `unique` rows so that there is only one row per group. We `rbind` this dataframe with the groups which are `!all_NA`.

```
all_NA <- with(df1, ave(is.na(val), id, FUN = all))
rbind(unique(transform(df1[all_NA, ], val = 0)), df1[!all_NA, ])

#  id val
#1  a   0
#5  b   1
#6  b   2
#7  b   2
#8  b   3
```

---

`dplyr` option looks ugly but one way is to make two groups of dataframes one with groups of all `NA` values and other with groups of all non-NA values. For groups with all `NA` values we add row with it's `id` and `val` as 0 and bind this to the other group.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1 %>%
            group_by(id) %>%
            filter(all(!is.na(val))), 
          df1 %>%
             group_by(id) %>%
             filter(all(is.na(val))) %>%
             ungroup() %>%
             summarise(id = unique(id), 
                       val = 0)) %>%
arrange(id)


#   id      val
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1  a         0
#2  b         1
#3  b         2
#4  b         2
#5  b         3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option too:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(.,is.na(.),0))) %>% 
  slice(4:nrow(.))
```

This gives:

```
 id val
1  a   0
2  b   1
3  b   2
4  b   2
5  b   3
```

Alternative:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(replace(.,is.na(.),0))) %>% 
  unique()
```

**UPDATE based on other requirements:**
Some users suggested to test on this dataframe. Of course this answer assumes you'll look at everything by hand. Might be less useful if you have to look at everything  by "hand" but here goes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4), val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))


df1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
  mutate(val=ifelse(id=="a",0,val)) %>% 
  slice(4:nrow(.))
```

This yields:

```
 id val
1  a   0
2  b   1
3  b   2
4  b   2
5  b   3
6  c  NA
7  c   2
8  c  NA
9  c   3
```

Comment: where did 4 come from?

Comment: The solution produces four 0s. We're only interested in having 1?

Comment: What if one group has 4 and another 3?

Comment: Sorry I only answered based on the question. Maybe then we could twist things up, not sure though!

Comment: Consider this example - `df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4),
                  val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))` I think here OP wants to remove `NA` values for `A` group only, not the rest

Comment: Plus not sure what OP's intention is yet. Seems everyone interpreted the question differently.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the `df` to make example more exhaustive -

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4),
                  val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(case=sum(is.na(val))==n(), row_num=row_number() ) %>%
  mutate(val=ifelse(is.na(val)&case,0,val)) %>%
  filter( !(case&row_num!=1) ) %>%
  select(id, val)
```

**Output**

```
  id      val
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         0
2 b         1
3 b         2
4 b         2
5 b         3
6 c        NA
7 c         2
8 c        NA
9 c         3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base approach, one that doesn't maintain the order of the rows and takes advantage of factors remembering lost values:

```
df1 <- na.omit(df1)

df1 <- rbind(
  df1, 
  data.frame(
    id  = levels(df1$id)[!levels(df1$id) %in% df1$id], 
    val = 0)
  )
```

I do personally prefer the dplyr approach given by Sotos, as I don't like `rbind`-ing data.frames back together so it's a matter of taste, but this isn't unbearably complicated by my eye. It's easy enough to adapt to a character `id` column with a `unique(df1$id)` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
res <- lapply(split(df1, df1$id), function(DF){
  if(anyNA(DF$val)) {
    i <- is.na(DF$val)
    DF$val[i] <- 0
    DF <- rbind(DF[i & !duplicated(DF[i, ]), ], DF[!i, ])
  }
  DF
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  id val
#1  a   0
#2  b   1
#3  b   2
#4  b   2
#5  b   3
```

**Edit.**

A `dplyr` solution could be the following.
It was tested with the original dataset posted by the OP, with the dataset in [Vivek Kalyanarangan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022536/replace-all-na-values-for-variable-with-one-row-equal-to-0/54023202#54023202) and with the dataset in [markus' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022536/replace-all-na-values-for-variable-with-one-row-equal-to-0/54022867#comment94882339_54022867), renamed `df2` and `df3`, respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

na2zero <- function(DF){
  DF %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(val), 0, val),
           crit = val == 0 & duplicated(val)) %>%
    filter(!crit) %>%
    select(-crit)
}

na2zero(df1)
na2zero(df2)
na2zero(df3)
```

Comment: Rui, try with `df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2), val = c(NA, 1, 2, 3))`. Unfortunately your solution doesn't return a data frame with only three rows.

Comment: @markus No, it doesn't. The `NA` is replaced by a `0` and the other value of `val` is not `NA` so both must be in the output. At least that's how I'm understanding the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

One may try this :

```
df1 = data.frame(id = rep(c("a", "b","c"), each = 4),
                  val = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 3,NA,2,NA,3))
df1
#   id val
#1   a  NA
#2   a  NA
#3   a  NA
#4   a  NA
#5   b   1
#6   b   2
#7   b   2
#8   b   3
#9   c  NA
#10  c   2
#11  c  NA
#12  c   3
```

**Task** is to remove all rows corresponding to any `id` IFF `val` for the corresponding `id` is all `NA`s and add new row with this `id` and `val = 0`.
In this example, `id = a`.

Note : `val` for `c` also has `NA`s but all the `val` corresponding to `c` are not `NA` therefore we need to remove the corresponding row for `c` where `val = NA`.

So lets create another column say, `val2` which indicates `0` means its all `NA`s and 1 otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 = df1 %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(val2 = if_else(condition = all(is.na(val)),true = 0, false =  1))
df1

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#   id      val  val2
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a        NA     0
#2 a        NA     0
#3 a        NA     0
#4 a        NA     0
#5 b         1     1
#6 b         2     1
#7 b         2     1
#8 b         3     1
#9 c        NA     1
#10 c        2     1
#11 c       NA     1
#12 c        3     1
```

Get the list of `id`s with corresponding `val = NA` for all.

```
all_na = unique(df1$id[df1$val2 == 0])
```

Then remove the`id`s from the dataframe `df1` with `val = NA`.

```
df1 = na.omit(df1)
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
# id      val  val2
# <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 b         1     1
# 2 b         2     1
# 3 b         2     1
# 4 b         3     1
# 5 c         2     1
# 6 c         3     1
```

And create a new dataframe with `id`s in `all_na` and `val = 0`

```
all_na_df = data.frame(id = all_na, val = 0) 
all_na_df
# id val
# 1  a   0
```

then combine these two dataframes.

```
df1 = bind_rows(all_na_df, df1[,c('id', 'val')])
df1

#    id val
# 1  a   0
# 2  b   1
# 3  b   2
# 4  b   2
# 5  b   3
# 6  c   2
# 7  c   3
```

Hope this helps and Edits are most welcomed :-)